# KeyMapper's changes not taking effect (WIN7)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to remap a few keys on my keyboard. I downloaded KeyMapper and applied the appropriate settings. No effect. I got it to output a registry file and ran that. Still no effect (obviously with the required restarts and log off/ons). What could I be doing wrong?

The keys I'm mapping for those who are interested are:

Home to PrtScrn

Right Shift to End

Right Control to Home

The first is because its a Mac keyboard on a PC, the last two just because it will make programming slightly easier for getting to the start and end of lines.

Any help or recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cheers! That worked! Thanks so much. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it so you can get some well-deserved rep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) instead; it has never failed me yet:

[image: 1]

Comment: Cheers that worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Not sure why KeyMapper didn't though, but then again I've never used it myself since SharpKeys has always worked for me.